# Scenic route from Switzerland to Calais

Tags: france, automobiles

I'm planning to go to England by car for holidays. I would like to take a nice route from Switzerland to Calais where I will take the ferry to England. I don't mind that it will take longer of course.

I hope to avoid some motorways, but to see some nice landscapes and have a relaxed drive. I will start in Switzerland near Zurich.

The direct route is about 800km. When I take the scenic route I expect to stay somewhere for the night, and make it a two day trip.

So do you have suggestions for a nice route for getting from Switzerland to Calais by car?

Comment: Use a travel planner and set it to 'no motorways' or 'touristic' or whatever they offer for the route with the best views. France is loaded with great places and good views. You can also combine part motorways with part country roads. And use the points of interest, if available.

Comment: Buy regional Michelin road maps and use the roads highlighted in green as a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it counts as “scenic” but there is something significant and timely you can find all along this route: World War I battlefields and cemeteries.

A few suggestions:

- [Douamont Ossuary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douaumont_Ossuary) and the Verdun battlefield
- The Somme, between Bapaume, Albert and Péronne
- [Chemin des Dames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemin_des_Dames)
- [Destroyed villages in the Meuse area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_French_villages_destroyed_in_World_War_I)

It can be quite moving and depressing.

Comment: @GayotFow That's a bit further north but good also. The Chemin des Dames has seen fighting in 1870 and in both World Wars also.